# How to use like in where condition in sequelize, node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to filter the data from table in which i want to use multiple condition. when i apply like in query it show application error.
how to do the same?

I am using nodejs framework, express, sequelize and mysql.

```
router.get('/booking-information', function (req, res) {
  // Get orders
  Promise.all([Order.findAll({
    /*where: {
      endDate: null,
    },*/
    order: [
    ['id', 'DESC'],
    ]
    }),
    Professional.findAll({where: {status : '1'}})
  ])
    .then(([orders, professionals]) => {
      orders.map((order) => {
        let professionalsInSameArea = professionals.filter((professional) => {
          return (professional.service === order.service || professional.secondary_service LIKE '%' + order.service + '%') && (professional.area === order.area || order.area === professional.secondary_area);
        });
        order.professionals = [...professionalsInSameArea]
        return order;
      });
      res.render('booking-information', {title: 'Technician', orders: orders, user: req.user});
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
});
```

I want to filter out the professionals in same area and same service for which a order placed.

Comment: Do you want to query the model? what is `orders`, is it the result? Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable exaple.

Comment: I have added complete code

Comment: Can any one please help me from this issue: How i can apply in this line: return (professional.service === order.service || professional.secondary_service LIKE '%' + order.service + '%') && (professional.area === order.area || order.area === professional.secondary_area); Is it true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, You can just use [`String.indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function in your case Because

By definition, `String LIKE %word%` means if the `String` **contains** `word`:

```
router.get('/booking-information', function (req, res) {
  // Get orders
  Promise.all([
    Order.findAll({
      /*where: {
        endDate: null,
      },*/
      order: [
        ['id', 'DESC'],
      ]
    }),
    Professional.findAll({
      where: {
        status: '1'
      }
    })
  ])
    .then(([orders, professionals]) => {
      orders.map((order) => {
        let professionalsInSameArea = professionals.filter((professional) => {
          return (professional.service === order.service 
                 || (professional.secondary_service || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((order.service || '').toLowerCase()) > -1) 
            && (professional.area === order.area 
                || order.area === professional.secondary_area);
        });
        order.professionals = professionalsInSameArea; //you don't need to spread, then make an array
        return order;
      });
      res.render('booking-information', { title: 'Technician', orders: orders, user: req.user });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But it show error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null @Aritra

Comment: Yes you have to handle nulls as well, depending on the data. I just showed you how can you do this in optimal situation.

Comment: Handled the nulls for now.

Answer (score 4):

```
you can use Op operator in query
like :-

const Op = Sequelize.Op

{
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      fieldName: {
        [Op.like]: 'abc%'
      }
    },
    {
      fieldName: {
        [Op.like]: '%abc%'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How i can apply in this line: return (professional.service === order.service || professional.secondary_service LIKE '%' + order.service + '%') && (professional.area === order.area || order.area === professional.secondary_area);