# Similar string matching in Sequelize MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and JS and might not know all operators so I want to ask if there's any way to retrieve an entry from a database which is similar to but not an exact match. So for example the string I'm searching for is `+921234567890` but in the database its stored as `+92-1234567890`, separated with a hyphen for country dialing codes.
The db I'm using is MySQL.
I tried this which I know is incorrect but I'm not sure how to move ahead:

```
 where: {
        cell: {
          [Op.or]: {
            [Op.like]: "%-%",
            [Op.eq]: cellNumber,
          },
        },
```

Comment: Can you place your codes you have been trying ,so can get more clarification

Comment: check if this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092309/how-to-use-like-in-where-condition-in-sequelize-node-js

Comment: @Nithin-Techidiots , I did see it and used the `like` operator however I still need to match the numbers themsleves

Comment: This is not really a task for like operator. You better add the hyphen to the search string at the appropriate place and use equality operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore characters on a MYSQL SELECT LIKE %...%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850180/how-to-ignore-characters-on-a-mysql-select-like)

Comment: @doublesharp That question is same but I'm using Sequelize with MySQL which does not provide the replace operator

Comment: @anosha_rehan I posted an answer, it does have `REPLACE_REGEX`

Comment: @doublesharp, I'm using Sequelize 6.* and I keep on getting an error on `sequelize.where` which is `No overload matches this call`

Comment: @anosha_rehan would need to see your code, that function does exist

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`REGEX_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) sql function to replace any non-numeric characters in the `cell` column before comparing to your input. Use the `sequelize.where()`, `sequelize.fn()`, and `sequelize.col()` functions to generate the query. Assuming your table is `model` and Model is `Model`.

```js
const cellNumber = 1234567890;

const results = await Model.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('REGEXP_REPLACE', sequelize.col('model.cell'), '[a-zA-Z]+', ''),
    '=',
    cellNumber
  ),
});
```

This should generate SQL similar to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `model`
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(`model`.`cell`, '[a-zA-Z]+', '') = 1234567890;
```

Comment: So I ended up solving the issue. I stopped getting the error after I replaced `REGEXP_REPLACE` with `REPLACE`. But thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue was solved using raw sql query but for anyone looking for an answer when using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, you should use `REPLACE` with `sequelize.literal`:

`cell: { [Op.eq]: this.sequelize.literal("REPLACE('cell','-','')") }`

Comment: This is not the best solution for your issue, I recommend using `REGEX_REPLACE` and a regular expression. Your code will only remove hyphens for example but would fail on a US phone like `(415) 555-1234` because of the spaces and parens.